# What is ‘a bell-covered hat’?

Tags: meaning, collocation

> Harry looked up and saw, floating twenty feet above them, Peeves the Poltergeist, a little man in **a bell-covered hat** and orange bow tie, his wide, malicious face contorted with concentration as he took aim again.
>   (p172, Harry Potter 4, US edition)

Would you get some specific picture from ‘a bell-covered hat’?

A flop hat, like a bellflower?

A clown hat, whose every horn has a small bell on its tip?

A strange hat, which is encrusted with bells?

I’d be happy if you could give me the right image of the hat.

Comment: @Random832,@Ham and Bacon     I got a good understanding thanks to both of you. All in all, I took it as an expression which needs paraphrase or explanation to make a clear image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would picture "A clown hat, whose every horn has a small bell on its tip", but I think it's an odd way of saying it.

One of the only unrelated results I could find on Google is [this](http://books.google.com/books?id=ovRvBtnmov4C&pg=PT108&lpg=PT108&dq=%22bell%20covered%20hat%22%20-peeves&source=bl&ots=5wfUFK_9X8&sig=aALEP9qS-B1K12m4ehBwGW0nM4A&hl=en&ei=a5jxTZHcJ5KEtgfP9uGoAw&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=3&ved=0CCEQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=%22bell%20covered%20hat%22%20-peeves&f=false), which has a character who is dressed as a jester - jesters stereotypically wear such multi-pointed hats.

Comment: Thank you! I read the article you mentioned. ‘His bell-covered hat’ is rephrased as ‘his jester hat’ a few lines later. It showed me clearly one possible picture of the hat.

Comment: Do keep in mind, though, that the fact that there were only a few results means it's not a common phrase for this, and the two authors may well have meant different things.

Answer (score 2):

The text says it is a **bell-covered hat**, but does not mention that it is in the shape of a jester, or has horns to it, so I would take that it meant

> a strange hat, which is encrusted with bells.

Which would suit his orange bow tie

Comment: Thank you! Your answer strongly supports my understanding.